# Pandas: rolling std deviation/mean by trading days

Tags: python, pandas, trading

I am trying to extract the rolling std deviation and mean on trading data by using `rolling_*` functions of `pandas`.

My data looks like:

```
Tick   Trading_day  Trade_price  

VOD     2013-1-2     30.23
VOD     2013-1-2     30.33
VOD     2013-1-2     30.24
VOD     2013-1-5     31.23
VOD     2013-1-5     30.23
VOD     2013-1-6     30.23
VOD     2013-1-7     30.23
VOD     2013-1-8     30.23
VOD     2013-1-9     30.23

...     .......      .....

RBS     2013-1-2     15.23
...     .......      .....
```

Basically, I want to work out mean price and standard deviation of price by **each stock** based on  **(-3, +3) trading days**.

Please note there are two **tricky things** here:

1. **There are various number of trades** in each trading day (frequent trades in liquid day).
2. Those are trading days (**not calendar days**), therefore they are not in sequence.

My ideal output is

```
Tick   Trading_day  mean_price   std_price  

VOD     2013-1-2     30.23         0.13
VOD     2013-1-5     30.11         0.09
VOD     2013-1-6     30.24         0.15
...     .....        .......      .....
RBS     2013-1-2     15.23         0.19
```

Anyone has idea ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: IIUC I think you can do `df.set_index('Trading_day', drop=False).groupby('Tick').apply(lambda x: pd.rolling_mean(x, window = 1, freq='6d'))` and `df.set_index('Trading_day', drop=False).groupby('Tick').apply(lambda x: pd.rolling_std(x, window = 1, freq='6d'))`

Comment: If there are multiple trades for the same security on any given date, how do you want to calculate the mean price?  Ideally it would be weighted by the size of the trade, but that information is not provided.  If it is not available, then I'd assume you'd want a simple mean?

Comment: In addition, is it possible that no price is given on a trading day?  Or that a price is given on a non trading day?  That is, can we assume there is a price given on each trading day and all prices occur on trading days?

Comment: @EdChum  thank you very much

Comment: @Alexander yes. I just want simple equal weight mean

Comment: @Alexander Its possible that no price is given on a trading day. But if this is the case, the trading day will be deleted from the data.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the data I'm using in this example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Tick': ['VOD'] * 7 + ['RBS'] * 2,
                   'Trade_price': [30.23, 30.24, 31.23, 30.23, 30.23, 30.23, 30.23, 14.11, 15.23],
                   'Trading_day': ['1/2/13', '1/2/13', '1/5/13', '1/5/13', '1/6/13', '1/7/13', '1/8/13', '1/2/13', '1/5/13']})
```

First, let's use [`.to_datetime()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and make your date column Pandas timestamps if they are not already.

```
df['Trading_day'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Trading_day)
```

Next, well group and transform the data so that we take the mean price for each ticker on any given day and that dates are unique in the index:

```
df = df.groupby(['Trading_day', 'Tick']).Trade_price.mean().unstack()
>>> df 
Tick           RBS     VOD
Trading_day               
2013-01-02   14.11  30.235
2013-01-05   15.23  30.730
2013-01-06     NaN  30.230
2013-01-07     NaN  30.230
2013-01-08     NaN  30.230
```

Now, you want to "work out mean price and standard deviation of price by each stock based on (-3, +3) trading days.".  One way to do this is to use [`pd.rolling_mean()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.rolling_mean.html) and center the results.  Given the limited data set, I am using a 3 day centered window (i.e. the prior day, current day and following day). You will want to use a 7 day window to get +/- 3 trading days.

```
>>> pd.rolling_mean(df, 3, center=True) 
Tick         RBS        VOD
Trading_day                
2013-01-02   NaN        NaN
2013-01-05   NaN  30.398333
2013-01-06   NaN  30.396667
2013-01-07   NaN  30.230000
2013-01-08   NaN        NaN
```

And to get a rolling standard deviation, just use `pd.rolling_std()`.